# want to add milliseconds in time stamp of console output using gawk bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, pipe, milliseconds

I am using following snippet to add timestamp to console output

```
command | gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }'
```

how to add milliseconds to it?

Comment: i was trying to add the output of `date +%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N` to it but was unable to figure out the syntax for it

Comment: Is this because you need the detail, or because you are feeding the output to something that expects a milliseconds field?

Comment: Why do you want to add milliseconds? The result isn't going to be accurate with respect to the command running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not a simple bash solution? You can read each line and prepend a timestamp using the `date` command, e.g.

```bash
command | while read -r line; do printf "%s %s\n" "$(date +'%F %T.%03N')" "$line"; done
```

**Example Use/Output**

Sample lines:

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

Timestamped output:

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt | 
while read line; do printf "%s %s\n" "$(date +'%F %T.%03N')" "$line"; done
2022-06-24 00:45:28.030 This is a tale
2022-06-24 00:45:28.031 Of Captain Jack Sparrow
2022-06-24 00:45:28.033 A Pirate So Brave
2022-06-24 00:45:28.035 On the Seven Seas.
```

(**note:** thank you @jhnc for the GNU `date` `%03N` specifier)

With bash you can also use *process substitution* to feed the timestamp loop, e.g.

```bash
while read -r line; do 
  printf "%s %s\n" "$(date +'%F %T.%03N')" "$line"
done < <(command)
```

Comment: GNU date supports flags: eg. `%03N`

Comment: Oh --- that's very nice -- thank you!

Comment: Other than relative order, the millisecond numbers being produced will be totally meaningless with respect to when the command is outputting lines that you're going to attach the timestamps to.

Comment: @EdMorton - thanks, oversight corrected. (again)

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to the original `date` idea:

```
 echo -ne "[$( date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N')] "; command
```

Comment: this wont satisfy the requirement, as the command is a long-running process and want to append time stamp to each output not just print timestamp

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question ...

Answer (score 0):

@Rohit : unless I'm missing something from the `gawk` manual, I don't see it, unless you want to use the `gawk` extension `time`. Otherwise, this is how I get `microsecs` for my various `awk`s :

```
 {m,g}awk '{ OFMT="%.15f"

   print substr("",(__="gdate +\47%s.%N\47" \         # gnu-date
                    )|getline _,    close(__)) +_ }' 

   1656047978.467053890228271
```

- `It only has 53-bit of precision (or 52, depending on who you ask about the implied bit), so those extra decimal points are mere optical illusions`
- `The "substr()" here neither outputs anything nor affect what's being returned. It's sole  functionality is to act as a temporary staging area of sorts`

|

```
 ( I use substr() encapsulations as a generic way to 
   swap values between 2 variables w/o

     using a temp var, 
     an external function call, or 
     bit-wise XOR techniques (awk specs intentionally dont offer it)

   in a sense, it kinda gives a sorta similar,
   but certainly not identical,
   feel to more modern languages returning tuples)
```

That said, if you aren't constrained by `gawk-only requirement`, i'm aware of 1 variant of `awk` that offers millisec times without going external :

```
 mawk2 '{ print substr("",srand(),srand()) srand() }'

 #srand1656049345.921576#
```